# ImageView is Crashing The Application

Tags: android, eclipse, crash, imageview

This application works perfectly on my android 2.1 but when i use it on my Galaxy S3 4.1.1 it doesnt work at all and crashed

The LogCat

```
12-22 22:38:39.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25460): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-22 22:38:39.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25460): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.TripleC.twenty20/com.TripleC.twenty20.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
12-22 22:38:39.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25460):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2088)
12-22 22:38:39.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25460):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113)
12-22 22:38:39.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25460):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139)
12-22 22:38:39.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25460):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1224)
12-22 22:38:39.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25460):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-22 22:38:39.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25460):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-22 22:38:39.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25460):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
12-22 22:38:39.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25460):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-22 22:38:39.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25460):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-22 22:38:39.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25460):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
12-22 22:38:39.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25460):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
12-22 22:38:39.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25460):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-22 22:38:39.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25460): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
12-22 22:38:39.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25460):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
12-22 22:38:39.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25460):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
12-22 22:38:39.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25460):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
```

Also here is my XML build, i see that it is the picture i have put up but i dont know what about the picture is the problem, if i delete it, the app works perfectly but i need the picture there

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/wood"
 >

<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:text="Welcome To the Beta Version of 20/20's Youth Ministry New App"
android:gravity="center"
android:id="@+id/fragment_main_textview" 
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textSize="10pt"
/>

<ImageView 
android:layout_width="120pt"
android:id="@+id/mainLogo" 
android:layout_height="120pt"
android:background="@drawable/glasses"
android:layout_gravity="center"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

It is now saying this

```
12-22 23:16:31.465: A/libc(3371): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x000009a4 (code=1), thread 3371 (ripleC.twenty20)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is in the size of the image you gonna have to set for imageview, As you already mentioned that in previous versions,it works perfect,but in newer versions,it is crashing you app,it means you haven;t added images in drawable folder, add drawable folder in your resources and add `glasses` image in that folder,then clean your project and run your application,your problem would be solved then.

your error is at:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
12-22 22:38:39.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25460):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
12-22 22:38:39.756: E/AndroidRuntime(25460):
```

and exception is generated on  line #20 and it is image view.

Comment: Thank you but it is still crashing and now saying this "12-22 23:16:31.465: A/libc(3371): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x000009a4 (code=1), thread 3371 (ripleC.twenty20)"

Comment: yes that's right, I thought you already did that, 
nice log tracking Hamad :)

Comment: if you all appreciate this,then do appreciate it by up voting too :) @ZORRO_BLANCO

Answer (score 1):

Are you scaling the layout
it is null pointer that means Android is not able to find your Drawable id(glasses),
put same image in your scaled drawables or simply create a drawable folder and keep glasses in drawable folder.
then it should work fine.

Comment: I did exactly that but it still crashed and saying tis "12-22 23:16:31.465: A/libc(3371): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x000009a4 (code=1), thread 3371 (ripleC.twenty20)
"

Comment: remove application from your device, clean application and then try giving a new build,
[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20192193/app-randomly-crashes-with-a-libc-fatal-signal-11)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, but I found the image with depth 8 cause the problems.
So I use another image with other depth than 8.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because of resource dpi problem, please put resources in drawable & layout directory & try, no extension like drawable-hdpi.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in the size of the image you gonna have to set the scale to fit XY, and set the layout width and height to "wrap_content" also the layout_centerInParent to true, I believe you need all these properties to be set not only one of them:

```
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

I hope that will help you ...

Comment: Thank you a lot, but it didnt work, the same reason for the crash comes up

Comment: I am not sure about your application, but we can just try to remove all other properties and set these properties, sure you gonna heave to leave the id too, then run, tell me what happens ;)

Comment: I tried it again but it still crashed :( , might it be that the picture is in the wrong drawable folder?

Comment: Put your picture in the "drawable" folder and check please.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a simple thing. Resolution/Dimension of the image file is too high. Just changing the resolution will fix it for sure. That is the only problem here.